# Is there a way to transfer data stored in an SQLite database from a react-native app to a native android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, react-native, android-room

I have a react-native app that uses the [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage) plugin to store user data. Is there an easy/automated way to transfer the data stored to a new version of this app written entirely in java/android, using the [Room Persistence Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html)?

Comment: Do you know all the database/table names? Have you tried following [this guide](https://medium.com/google-developers/7-steps-to-room-27a5fe5f99b2)?

Comment: @theFunkyEngineer that's a great write-up on implementing Room in an android app but it still doesn't help me with making a transition from react-native SQLite to Android.